# Extend Magento Catalog Database Structure

Tags: magento

I am preparing for Magento certification and this question really stuck me in between. I don't quite understand how to extend Magento's catalog db structure, in fact, I don't completely understand the question to be honest.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: What are you referring to? The study guide of Magento for the developer certification? If so, please specify which page/paragraph the question is. Thanks

Comment: @mpaepper thanks for your comment. In the Magento Self-assessment Checklist PDF, you can find it in "Catalog" section, under "Other Skills": "Troubleshoot, customize, and extend the Magento Catalog DB Structure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more up-to-date and more in-depth document where there is no such question in section 7. Find this document for download here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/ in resources tab.

I can see your question in the self-assessment checklist where it states:

"Troubleshoot, customize, and extend the Magento Catalog DB Structure"

Since this question does not pop-up in the newer document my guess is that it is not that important. You should have a general understanding of the main database tables and how they belong together and how to add new attributes to entities in the setup program.

I just passed the certified developer exam and I cannot remember any question asking any specifics with regards to customizing the database structure.

Comment: Thanks for returning, I also just passed the MCD exam :)

Comment: Congrats @Kalpesh how much gems you collected :) ?